# Copy an SQLite .db3 file to OneDrive app folder xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, onedrive, sqlite-net

I have an .db3 file in the special folder of my xamarin forms android app. I want to copy this file to the onedrive app folder. I am unsure how to go about this.
Please any clue would be appreciated. I am using msgraph .net ask

Answer (score 0):

For OneDrive, there is a REST API you can use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/

Or a third party, CloudRail has a library for Xamarin : https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Xamarin.OneDrive

Besides，there are many tutorials when you research on google by key word `xamarin onedrive`.
For example:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/adding-storage-mobile-apps-onedrive-business/

Comment: Thank you for the links. I have been able implement the Onedrive setup for conecting to a personal account and uploading the file. However, the .db3 sqlite file is empty. I guess  my main problem is how to copy a .db3 file from one folder to another.

Comment: No. I was looking at using the MSGraph .NET SDK not the REST API